# batch fbx export in maya

Tags: python, export, maya, fbx

Could somebody suggest a way to batch export fbx files from Maya.

The way I have it written at the moment? I have Fbx export script working on a scene that is open in Maya. I want to take it a step further, and wrote a little script that would locate all maya file in a chosen folder which then I want to batch convert and export as fbx to the same folder. Ideally, I wanted to have this process to run without opening it in Maya, on background so to speak.
This is what I have so far:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from CreatureExport import CreatureAnimBakeProcess

def exportAllAnim():
    path = r'F:\Characters\Creatures\Animation'
    print path

    files = cmds.getFileList(folder=path, filespec='*.ma')
    print files
    CreatureAnimBakeProcess.createDirectory()
    for f in files:
        print f
        cmds.file(f, open=True, force=True)
        CreatureAnimBakeProcess.expProcess()
```

Can anyone suggest way to do that? Or at least where I could read on a way to do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into batch mode and command line evaluation of scripts in maya, covered for example, in this article - https://www.xingyulei.com/post/maya-batch-mode/

maya has an external python interpreter mayapy (which is called batch mode quite often in tech discussions) - https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2022/ENU/Maya-Scripting/files/GUID-D64ACA64-2566-42B3-BE0F-BCE843A1702F-htm.html

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'll have a look through those links